# How can I add a mouselistener to my rectangle(custom button) to re-execute paintcomponent in java?

Tags: java, swing

My script generates a game board of hexagonal tiles with randomly selected resources and dice number assignments.  I want to add a button to the GUI that regenerates the board.  Since I use paintcomponent in a JPanel, I have to use a custom button class that I created.  This class simply draws a rectangle based on parameters specified.  I want to add a mouselistener to this rectangle that clears the JPanel contents and re-executes the drawGUI() method.  The board is generated completely fine, but the mouselistener that I have does not currently do anything.  Am I putting the mouselstener in the right place in my code?  Am I writing the mouselistener correctly?  What am I doing wrong?  Here is my code:

The java for the main window:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class SettlersofCatan extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final int WIDTH = 1200;
    private final int HEIGHT = 800;
    private ArrayList<String> resources = new ArrayList();
    private Hashtable<String, Integer> colors = new Hashtable();
    public ArrayList<Integer> diceSpaces = new ArrayList<>();
    public Tile[] tiles = new Tile[19];
    public Object[] rsrcs;
    public CButton regenerate = new CButton();

    private Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18);
    FontMetrics metrics;

    public SettlersofCatan() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        resources.add("Brick");
        resources.add("Brick");
        resources.add("Brick");
        resources.add("Wool");
        resources.add("Wool");
        resources.add("Wool");
        resources.add("Wool");
        resources.add("Lumber");
        resources.add("Lumber");
        resources.add("Lumber");
        resources.add("Lumber");
        resources.add("Stone");
        resources.add("Stone");
        resources.add("Stone");
        resources.add("Wheat");
        resources.add("Wheat");
        resources.add("Wheat");
        resources.add("Wheat");

        colors.put("Brick", 0x990000);
        colors.put("Wool", 0xFFFFFF);
        colors.put("Lumber", 0x006600);
        colors.put("Stone", 0x666666);
        colors.put("Wheat", 0xFFFF33);
        colors.put("Wasteland", 0xCC9966);

        diceSpaces.add(2);
        diceSpaces.add(3);
        diceSpaces.add(3);
        diceSpaces.add(4);
        diceSpaces.add(4);
        diceSpaces.add(5);
        diceSpaces.add(5);
        diceSpaces.add(6);
        diceSpaces.add(6);
        diceSpaces.add(8);
        diceSpaces.add(8);
        diceSpaces.add(9);
        diceSpaces.add(9);
        diceSpaces.add(10);
        diceSpaces.add(10);
        diceSpaces.add(11);
        diceSpaces.add(11);
        diceSpaces.add(12);

        long seed = System.nanoTime();
        Collections.shuffle(resources, new Random(seed));
        Collections.shuffle(diceSpaces, new Random(seed));

        int index = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 18 + 1);

        resources.add(index, "Wasteland");
        diceSpaces.add(index, 7);

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        drawGUI(g);

    }

    public void drawGUI(Graphics g){

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Point origin = new Point(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2);

        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_SQUARE, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER));
        g2d.setFont(font);
        metrics = g.getFontMetrics();

        drawCircle(g2d, origin, 380, true, true, 0x4488FF, 0);
        drawHexGridLoop(g2d, origin, 5, 50, 8);

        regenerate.Background = 0x000000;
        regenerate.Foreground = 0xFFFFFF;
        regenerate.Padding = "7 15";
        regenerate.Text = "Regenerate Board";
        regenerate.Position = new double[] {25, 25};
        regenerate.FontFamily = "Arial";
        regenerate.draw(g2d);
    }

    private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (regenerate.rect.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    repaint();
                    return;
                }
        }
    }

    private void drawHexGridLoop(Graphics g, Point origin, int size, int radius, int padding) {

        String rsrc;

        double ang30 = Math.toRadians(30);
        double xOff = Math.cos(ang30) * (radius + padding);
        double yOff = Math.sin(ang30) * (radius + padding);
        int half = size / 2;

        int i = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {

            int cols = size - java.lang.Math.abs(row - half);

            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {

                int xLbl = row < half ? col - row : col - half;
                int yLbl = row - half;
                int x = (int) (origin.x + xOff * (col * 2 + 1 - cols));
                int y = (int) (origin.y + yOff * (row - half) * 3);

                int diceNum = diceSpaces.get(i);
                rsrc = resources.get(i);
                drawHex(g, xLbl, yLbl, x, y, radius, i, colors.get(rsrc), diceNum);
                tiles[i] = new Tile(i, xLbl, yLbl, rsrc, diceSpaces.get(i));
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawHex(Graphics g, int posX, int posY, int x, int y, int r, int id, int color, int diceSpace) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        Hexagon hex = new Hexagon(x, y, r);
        String text = String.format("%s", diceSpace);
        int w = metrics.stringWidth(text);
        int h = metrics.getHeight();

        hex.draw(g2d, x, y, 0, color, true);
        hex.draw(g2d, x, y, 4, 0xFFDD88, false);

        g.setColor(new Color(0x000000));
        g.drawString(text, x - w/2, y + h/2);
    }

    private String coord(int value) {
        return (value > 0 ? "+" : "") + Integer.toString(value);
    }

    public void drawCircle(Graphics2D g, Point origin, int radius,
            boolean centered, boolean filled, int colorValue, int lineThickness) {
        // Store before changing.
        Stroke tmpS = g.getStroke();
        Color tmpC = g.getColor();

        g.setColor(new Color(colorValue));
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(lineThickness, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,
                BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));

        int diameter = radius * 2;
        int x2 = centered ? origin.x - radius : origin.x;
        int y2 = centered ? origin.y - radius : origin.y;

        if (filled)
            g.fillOval(x2, y2, diameter, diameter);
        else
            g.drawOval(x2, y2, diameter, diameter);

        // Set values to previous when done.
        g.setColor(tmpC);
        g.setStroke(tmpS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        SettlersofCatan p = new SettlersofCatan();

        f.setContentPane(p);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

CButton.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;

public class CButton {
    public int Background, Foreground;
    public int Width = 0;
    public int Height = 0;
    public String Padding;
    public int BorderWidth = 0;
    public int BorderColor = 0x000000;
    public double[] Position;
    public String FontFamily;
    public String Text = "";
    public Rectangle rect;

    CButton(){
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){


        Font font = new Font(FontFamily, Font.BOLD, 18);
        FontMetrics metrics;
        metrics = g2d.getFontMetrics(font);

        int paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom, paddingLeft, rx, ry, rw, rh, tx, ty, tw, th;
            String[] padding = Padding.split(" ");
            if(padding.length > 2){
                paddingTop = Integer.parseInt(padding[0]);
                paddingRight = Integer.parseInt(padding[1]);
                paddingBottom = Integer.parseInt(padding[2]);
                paddingLeft = Integer.parseInt(padding[3]);
            } else if(padding.length == 2){
                paddingTop = Integer.parseInt(padding[0]);
                paddingRight = Integer.parseInt(padding[1]);
                paddingBottom = Integer.parseInt(padding[0]);
                paddingLeft = Integer.parseInt(padding[1]);
            } else {
                paddingTop = Integer.parseInt(padding[0]);
                paddingRight = Integer.parseInt(padding[0]);
                paddingBottom = Integer.parseInt(padding[0]);
                paddingLeft = Integer.parseInt(padding[0]);
            }

        if(BorderWidth != 0){
            g2d.setColor(new Color(BorderColor));
            g2d.drawRect((int)Position[0], (int)Position[1], Width, Height);
        }

        tw = metrics.stringWidth(Text);
        th = metrics.getHeight();

        rx = (int) Position[0];
        ry = (int) Position[1];
        if(Padding != null){
            rw = tw + paddingLeft + paddingRight;
            rh = th + paddingTop + paddingBottom;
        } else if(Width != 0 && Height != 0){
           rw = Width;
           rh = Height;
        } else {
            rw = tw;
            rh = th;
        }

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(rx, ry, rw, rh);
        g2d.setColor(new Color(Background));
        g2d.fillRect((int) rect.getX(), (int) rect.getY(), (int) rect.getWidth(), (int) rect.getHeight());

        int x = ((rect.width - metrics.stringWidth(Text)) / 2) + (int) Position[0];
        int y = ((rect.height - metrics.getHeight()) / 2) + metrics.getAscent() + (int) Position[1];

        g2d.setColor(new Color(Foreground));
        g2d.drawString(Text, x, y);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to call `addMouseListener(yourMouseListener)`on a `Component`to receive mouse events.

You may do this with your `JPanel`, since your listener already checks if the rectangle part of interest is under the clicked `Point` :

```
addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
```

However, since the listener is on your panel and not on your "button", you may have to translate the `Point` depending on the location of your button, like :

```
private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
        Point clickedPoint = e.getPoint();
        if (regenerate.rect.contains(new Point(clickedPoint.x - regenerate.Position[0], clickedPoint.y - regenerate.Position[1]))) {
            repaint();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need the `return;` statement in `mousePressed` .

Comment: Now when I click the button I get java.lang.NullPointerException on the line with if (regenerate.rect.contains(...

Comment: In your `draw` method, replace `Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(rx, ry, rw, rh);` with `rect = new Rectangle(rx, ry, rw, rh);`. Also I am not sure of the second part of my answer, it seems that your code already takes care of the relative position, so try with your actual `MyMouseListener`, and if it works I'll remove this part of the answer.

Comment: So that got rid of the error, but the component is still not repainted.

Comment: What visual changes do you expect between two repaints ?

Comment: The colors of the tiles and their diceSpaces values.

Comment: a visual so you can better understand what I mean.  http://imgur.com/f6fyN6W The colors of the tiles and the numbers inside them are randomly generated.  When the button is clicked, I want the script to regenerate the colors and the numbers.

Comment: In that case you should probably add your `Collections.shuffle` statements in `mousePressed`, just before `repaint()` .

Answer (score 0):

You never instantiate `MyMouseListener` or add it to any component with [`addMouseListener()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener-java.awt.event.MouseListener-).